# change value of variable based on conditions php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have a class name that should change based on certain conditions but either my syntax or my logic seems to be incorrect as it doesn't work:

```
if ( $hometeam && ($homescore > $awayscore) || $awayteam && ($awayscore > $homescore)){
                        $status= 'win'; 
                    }                       
if ( $hometeam && ($homescore < $awayscore) || $awayteam && ($awayscore < $homescore)) {
                        $status= 'lose';
                    }                       
if ($homescore == $awayscore) {
                        $status= 'draw';
                    }
```

My elements each have a `class="<?php echo $status; ?>"` and I want them to be styled differently depending on the value of `$status`. I didn't use `else if` because I didn't want it to apply the value and stop but it looks like that is what is happening.

Edit: Some clarification:

```
<ul class="match group">    
                <li>
                    <ul class="team1 <?php echo $status; ?>">
                        <li class="teamname"><h2><?php echo $homename; ?></h2></li>  
                        <li class="teamscore"><?php echo $homescore; ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="team2 <?php echo $status; ?>">
                        <li class="teamname"><h2><?php echo $awayname?></h2></li>    
                        <li class="teamscore"><?php echo $awayscore?></li>                              
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><ul class="matchinfo">
                        <li><a href="reports.html#report4"><button>Get Report</button></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: phpMyCoder's answer is good, but you might need to consider the sport, it is possible for a game to have a winner and loser if the scores are tied: in football (soccer) cup matches can be tied, go to penalties but the result is still record as the goals in 90 minutes, but a team has won the game overall.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll have to ask how they want to treat penalty wins.

Comment: and Extra-time wins too, "1-1 FT, team A won 2-1 AET" is common on a lot of football websites/reports/results/. If you are focusing just on league games then this can be ignored obviously.

Comment: Its actually for a local league and they just the one report with room for a match description as well so I assume they will put any additional details there. Perhaps I will add an extra meta box for FT or AET and maybe a half time score.

Answer (score 2):

By your logic, there are only two possible outcomes for the value of `$status`: `'lose'` or `'draw'`.

Why is this? Basic logic says that unless there is a tie, a game will always have a winner. Your `if` statement lines up with this. Either `$homescore > $awayscore` or `$homescore < $awayscore` (or there is a tie). So in the event of a non-tie, one of the sides of your first if will evaluate to `true`, and therefore the entire condition will be `true` since `||` needs only one truthy. So unless there is a tie, `$status` will be set to `'win'`.

Moving on, basic logic will also tell us that a game always has a loser unless there is a tie. Again, your code conforms to this. In the event of a non-tie, one of the score will be less than the other and therefore your second if will evaluate to `true` like the first did. Now `$status = 'lose'`.

Now if there is a tie, `$status` would equal `'draw'`, but otherwise `$status` will always be `'lose'` because if the game has a winner, it also has a loser and `$status` is set to `'lose'` after it is set to `'win'`.

---

What you need here is a variable for the winner, loser, and for a draw. Like so:

```
$winner = '';
$loser  = '';
$draw   = false;

if($homescore > $awayscore) {
    $winner = 'home';
    $loser  = 'away';
} else if($homescore < $awayscore) {
    $winner = 'away';
    $loser  = 'home';
} else if($homescore === $awayscore) {
    $draw   = true;
}
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/EqTpxvNR))

This code also makes use of `else if`, because you don't need to evaluate the other conditions if you've determined who won and lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your conditions better.

```
if ( ($hometeam && ($homescore > $awayscore)) || ($awayteam && ($awayscore > $homescore))) 
{
  $status= 'win'; 
}                       
else if ( ($hometeam && ($homescore < $awayscore)) || ($awayteam && ($awayscore < $homescore))) 
{
  $status= 'lose';
} 
else 
{
  $status= 'draw';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. $status= 'win' for both teams wheras one should equal 'win' and the other 'lose.'

Comment: Perhaps we don't have enough information to give you the proper answer, however, the answer I gave works: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/h5n-g1u

Comment: The problem is that there are several matches and several teams so I want status to be evaluated more than once. Maybe this isn't possible?

Comment: In PHP, `else if` should be a single word to comply with PSR-12 coding standards.

Comment: @mickmackusa of course! Peeps must realize this answer was posted in '13 and PSR-12 came out like 6 years later though, but I agree!

Comment: I edit my old posts when I revisit them to improve the coding standard (which I wasn't aware of when I started developing).  I find it important to educate/inspire researchers by role modeling good scripting practices.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($homescore > $awayscore) {
        $homestatus = 'win';
        $awaystatus = 'lose';
    } else if ($homescore < $awayscore) { 
        $homestatus = 'lose';
        $awaystatus = 'win';
    } else {
        $homestatus = 'draw';
        $awaystatus = 'draw';
    }

<ul class="match group">    
            <li>
                <ul class="team1 <?php echo $homestatus; ?>">
                    <li class="teamname"><h2><?php echo $homename; ?></h2></li>  
                    <li class="teamscore"><?php echo $homescore; ?></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="team2 <?php echo $awaystatus; ?>">
                    <li class="teamname"><h2><?php echo $awayname?></h2></li>    
                    <li class="teamscore"><?php echo $awayscore?></li>                              
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><ul class="matchinfo">
                    <li><a href="the_permalink()"><button>Get Report</button></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```